Running HTML&JavaScript locally gets this error: TypeError: Module name, 'openai' does not resolve to a valid URL
I'm new to web dev and is following a tutorial on how to develop a web app using OpenAI API. The author runs the code in the course env called scrimba, while I'm developing on my MacBook.
This is what the app does: it's a simple html page (index.html) with a text area and a button, once hit the button, it invoke a method in the js script (index.js), which call OpenAI API. The returned result is displayed on the page. In index.html, the js script is included as follows:
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>

Here is the full implementation of index.js.
import OpenAI from 'openai';

import process from './env.js';

const openai = new OpenAI()

const setupTextarea = document.getElementById("setup-textarea");
const setupInputContainer = document.getElementById("setup-input-container");
const movieBossText = document.getElementById("movie-boss-text");

document.getElementById("send-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const userInput = setupTextarea.value;
  setupInputContainer.innerHTML =
      `<img src="images/loading.svg" class="loading" id="loading">`;
  movieBossText.innerText =
      `Ok, just wait a second while my digital brain digests that...`;

  fetchBotReply()
});

async function fetchBotReply() {
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages : [
      {role : "system", content : "You are a helpful assistant."},
      {
        role : "user",
        content : "Say something enthusiastic in less then 10 words"
      },
    ],
    model : "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  });

  console.log(completion.choices[0]);
}

I also added "type": "module" to the package.json file since node.js and express don't support ECMAScript modules IIUC.
I serve the pages using express successfully in my machine. But when I open the page in the browser, the js script doesn't seem to be loaded properly: I press the button and nothing happens. There is an error in the console saying:
TypeError: Module name, 'openai' does not resolve to a valid URL.

The openai module is installed successfully and imported correctly: I wrote another script (test.js) that calls the openai module and run it using node test.js and get the results successfully.
